# Mac SCSI Options

Tags: mac, scsi, hostadapter

We have a user with an old contraption (weird DigiData 1322A digitiser) that currently connects to a PowerMac G3.  The time has finally come to update the machine to either an iMac or Mac Pro

Due to the cost the iMac is the preferred option, however the only USB->SCSI adpater I can [find](http://www.ratocsystems.com/english/products/U2SCX.html) won't do [multiple LUNS](http://axograph.com/forum/index.php?topic=20.0) which are required.

So...  Is there a) For the iMac a better USB/FireWire/Thunderbolt to SCSI adapter that will do multiple LUNS.  Or b) can you still get PCI(e) SCSI cards for the Mac Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptec still makes PCIe SCSI adapters, as far as I know. They may be supported by OS X's native SCSI drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Atto still makes 2 PCIe Ultra320 SCSI cards, the UL5D and UL5D-LP (low profile). Both are OS X compatible and fit in the Mac Pro.

http://attotech.com/products/category.php?id=1&catid=2